# Javascript bookmarklet, search for regular expression, replace with html link dynamically

Tags: javascript, regex, bookmarklet

I have an html that has a lot of the following:

```
<TD CLASS="broke"> - WF-1234567 -  </TD>
<TD CLASS="broke"> - WF-1111111 -  </TD>
<TD CLASS="broke"> - WF-7654321 -  </TD>
```

I want to make a javascript bookmarklet to replace all the 7-digit numbers with a hyperlink.
How does one do this?

My attempt with many things wrong....

```
javascript:
var match=new RegExp("(- WF-....... - Review)","ig");
var x = document.getElementsByClassName("broke").innerHTML;
x=x.replace(match,<a href="www.blah.com/"+7digitSubsetofMatch>7digitlink</a>);
document.getElementsByClassName("browseItemLocation").innerHTML=x;
```

Comment: /WF-(\d{7})/ the number will be in $1 http://www.javascriptkit.com/jsref/regexp.shtml

Answer (score 1):

`getElementsByClassName` returns a list, not a single item with `innerHTML` available. you'll have to iterate over the list and handle each item individually.

```
javascript:(function(){

var elements = document.getElementsByClassName("broke");

for (var j = 0; j < elements.length; j++) {
```

to find and replace the number, you'll need to adjust your regex grouping- right now you're capturing a larger string without a way to get the digits. you do this by moving the parentheses to immediately surround the number

```
    var pattern = new RegExp("WF-(\\d+)", "ig");
    var match = elements[j].innerHTML.match(pattern);
```

if you had a successful match, then `match[0]` will be the whole string matched and `match[1]` will be the digits

you can't write literal html in javascript- it has to be a string.

```
    var x = elements[j].innerHTML.replace(match[1],
        '<a href="www.blah.com/' + match[1] + '">' + match[1] + '</a>');
```

then you cna replace your original html.

```
    elements[j].innerHTML = x;
}

})()
```

I don't know what your last line does but it seems unnecessary.